# Disable second graphic adapter on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, graphics-card, ubuntu-14.04

I'm using a Radeon R7 260x graphic adapter on Ubuntu 14.04, and I have 3 monitors connected to it.

My mousepointer flickers a bit and the display settings crash without a message.

I assume that this could be because of a second graphic adapter I have installed: An old Geforce 6610 XL.

I want to disable the Geforce, but I don't know how.

"lspci -vvnn | grep VGA" gives me the following output:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Bonaire XTX [Radeon R7 260X/360] [1002:6658] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
04:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation NV43 [GeForce 6610 XL] [10de:0145] (rev a2) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
```

**My questions:**

1) What part of the the name of the geforce I have to add to the blacklist like it is described e.g. here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1807422

2) Or is there a tool with a GUI which I could use to disable the device?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, found the solution:

Ubuntu uses the nouveau driver for the GeForce 6610 XL. So I had to add

```
# Don't load GeForce driver
blacklist nouveau
```

to /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf and restart the computer.

One more question: I read incidentally in a Forum, that the nouveau driver is used for the GeForce. How could I have found out this by myself? How can I get a list with the devices and the used driver in Ubuntu?

Comment: `lspci -k`. It's only for PCI(-E) devices though.